# Auto-Generated Email Based on Cell Values

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having trouble with my code and I'm not sure what's missing. I've built code a few times before but I am by no means an expert.

I am trying to send automatic email reminders when a cell value equals 30. My code successfully runs but it doesn't generate an email at all. What am I doing wrong?

I'm not sure what else to try, I've searched up how to make this happen but it isn't making sense to me on how exactly to make this happen.

```
function sendEmail(){
var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
var Dept = sSheet.getRange(1, 1, sSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
var PDName = sSheet.getRange(1, 3, sSheet.getLastRow(), 3);
var HRPname = sSheet.getRange(1, 26, sSheet.getLastRow(), 26);
var HRPemail = sSheet.getRange(1, 27, sSheet.getLastRow(), 27);
var AnniversaryDate = sSheet.getRange(1, 12, sSheet.getLastRow(), 12);
var DaysUntilAnni = sSheet.getRange(1, 13, sSheet.getLastRow(), 13);


if (DaysUntilAnni == 30){
  var subject = "Upcoming Postdoc Anniversary: " + PDName + " - " + AnniversaryDate;  
  var message = "Hi " + HRPname + "," + "\n\n" + "The Postdoc appointment for "+PDName+" in "+Dept+" has an appointment end date and/or anniversary date coming up on "+AnniversaryDate+". Please review this postdoc appointment and" +
                 "\n\n" + "take necessary action to extend their appointment and/or update level change based on their anniversary date." +
                 "\n\n" + "Please update the BEST Postdoc Tracker no later than " +AnniversaryDate+ " once the actions have been completed."

                 "\n\n" + "You will continue to receive weekly reminders regarding this action until the appointment end date or anniversary date has been updated in the BEST Postdoc Tracker.";     
  MailApp.sendEmail(HRPemail, subject, message);
 }  
}
```

My code should run daily and it should send emails to the appropriate people as listed in the google sheet.

Comment: Include your log in `View > Execution transcript` so we can see if it is getting to the `sendEmail()` code.

Comment: Thanks Ross! Its too long, so I made it into a pic link from my g drive.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I8ps5MlTFF08shURYE-0F8qUbtIcp8h2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There's your issue, `DaysUntilAnni` is not equal to 30 - so the code inside your `if` statement isn't triggering.

Comment: Gotcha, I guess I'm trying to tell it, when DaysUntilAnni equals 30, then send this email. That column in my sheet is a formula that calculates how many days until the anniversary date, I want whenever that number hits 30, to send an email. How would you go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In This line `var HRPemail = sSheet.getRange(1, 27, sSheet.getLastRow(), 27);` you have defined a range that begins on row 1, column 27, it is sSheet.getLastRow() rows and it has 27 columns and you never actually ran either the getValue() or the getValues() method on it.  So there is no data in HRPemail.  It's simply a range object which is just a collection of cells.

I suspect that you have a spreadsheet with several rows of data.  Right?

So after chatting with you I believe that you will have a little more success with this script.

```
function sendEmail(){
  var sSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var srg=sSheet.getRange(1,1,sSheet.getLastRow(),28);
  var sData=srg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<sData.length;i++) {
    var Dept = sData[i][0];//columns begin at 1 arrays begin at zero
    var PDName = sData[i][2];
    var HRPname = sData[i][25];
    var HRPemail = sData[i][2];
    var AnniversaryDate = sData[i][11];
    var DaysUntilAnni = sData[i][12];
    var Sent=sData[i][27];
    if (DaysUntilAnni == 30 && !Sent){
      var subject = "Upcoming Postdoc Anniversary: " + PDName + " - " + AnniversaryDate;  
      var message = "Hi " + HRPname + "," + "\n\n" + "The Postdoc appointment for "+PDName+" in "+Dept+" has an appointment end date and/or anniversary date coming up on "+AnniversaryDate+". Please review this postdoc appointment and" +
        "\n\n" + "take necessary action to extend their appointment and/or update level change based on their anniversary date." +
          "\n\n" + "Please update the BEST Postdoc Tracker no later than " +AnniversaryDate+ " once the actions have been completed."

          "\n\n" + "You will continue to receive weekly reminders regarding this action until the appointment end date or anniversary date has been updated in the BEST Postdoc Tracker.";     
      MailApp.sendEmail(HRPemail, subject, message);
      //i+1 is the row number assuming no headers
      sSheet.getRange(i+1,27).setValue('Sent');//if column 28 has data in it then an email will not be sent again on the next time through the loop.
    }  
  }
}
```

I haven't debugged it but it should come closer to what you want.  Look it over and ask questions.  If you have headers in your spreadsheet then we need to take that into account so let me know.

Comment: Hi MiMi, you're absolutely correct! Ok, I see what you're saying, I thought the range I gave it would also get the value, I do indeed have several rows of data.

Comment: Do you want to iterate through each row and send an email for each row?

Comment: Yes but, I only want it to send an email if it equals 30.

Comment: Yes.  I understand let's look at what this line does `if (DaysUntilAnni == 30 && !Sent){` It requires that DayUntilAnni equal 30 and that a previous email was not sent earlier.

Comment: I did increase size of the row by one column to accommodate the Sent column.  Is there room on your spreadsheet for that extra column?

Comment: You're the best! This is exactly what I wanted, THANK YOU!

Comment: I do indeed have room to add in one more column, I went ahead and added it to have the "Sent" cell.

Comment: When I debug scripts like this I usually disable the email line and I like to use the debugger and just go line by line making sure that every intermediate value is correct and sometime I even add extra intermediate values.  Also you may wish to use Logger.log to assist you in debugging.